# How to add a key value pair on existing object created via Vue Reactivity

Tags: object, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I already have an existing form which is dynamically created. However, I have problems with regards to adding a new set of key value pairs to the existing object. I have used the Vue Reactivity using the  this.$set() method with success on the **FIRST** pair only.

**Output**

```
{  "traveller_1": { "gender": "c" }, 
   "traveller_2": { "gender": "f" }, 
   "traveller_3": { "gender": "i" } 
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{ "traveller_1": { "firstname": "John", "age": "23", "gender": "m" }, 
  "traveller_2": { "firstname": "Jane", "age": "21", "gender": "f" }, 
  "traveller_3": { "firstname": "Jade", "age": "25", "gender": "f" }, 
 }
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stda7Lwm/

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="app"> {{ travellerDetails }}
   <div class="form-row" v-for="i in travellers"> 
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" v-for="(details, index) in bookingRequiredDetails">
         <label for="required-details">{{ details }}</label>
          <input 
             type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             @input="prop('traveller_' + i, details, $event)"
             placeholder="Required Details" 
           />
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted  () {
  },
  data () {
        return {
                test: { 'unit1' : { life: 30}},
            travellerDetails: { },
            travellers: 3,
            bookingRequiredDetails: ['fullname', 'age', 'gender'],
        };
    },
 methods: {
             prop: function(obj, prop, event) {
        this.$set(this.travellerDetails, obj, { [prop] : event.target.value } );
        console.log(this.travellerDetails);
       }
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding all object every time you assign new value. You should change a single prop only

```
   prop: function(obj, prop, event) {
     const data = this.travellerDetails[obj] || {}
     data[prop] = event.target.value
     this.travellerDetails = {
        ...this.travellerDetails,
        [obj]: {...data}
     }
   }
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for!! Thank you @ittus

Comment: Just a stupid question what's the use of the || {} on this.travellerDetails[obj] || {} @ittus

Comment: If `this.travellerDetails[obj]` is `undefined`, then data will be assigned to an empty object `{}`. You can check more at https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/

Comment: Oh I see Thank you once again!

Comment: Using `data[prop] = event.target.value` won't make the property reactive. The first property will be because it's a new object but the subsequent properties won't be. It will *appear* to be working fine because replacing `travellerDetails` triggers a re-render but the new property won't actually be reactive.

Comment: Can you try `[obj]: {...data}`?